# C# - Create custom object out of list of items returned from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, object, group-by

I got a list of data as an output from stored procedure as

```
 ID   YEAR  VALUE   TEST_VALUE  
------------------------------
 1    2019   78     3
 1    2020   12     3
 1    2021   56     3
 2    2019   23     2
 2    2020   89     2
 2    2021   34     2
```

Now I'm trying to create an object so that I can consume to render data on UI as follows:

```
Data
 -->[0]
     --> TEST_VALUE
     --> REPEATER_DATA ---this should be a list of values
        [0] 1    2019   78     3
        [1] 1    2020   12     3
        [2] 1    2021   56     3
 -->[1]
    --> TEST_VALUE
    --> REPEATER_DATA
      [0] 2    2019   23     2
      [1] 2    2020   89     2
      [2] 2    2021   34     2
```

Any suggestion on how to create a custom object out of this.

what I have done is

```
 public class TestData
 {
    public int TEST_VAL{ get; set; }
    public List<MY_SP_Result> Data { get; set; }
 }

and consuming this class as 

 class MyCls
 {
     public List<TestData> MyData {get;set;}
     public MyCls (List<MY_SP_Result> data)
     {
          MyData = new List<TestData>();
          var dt = new TestData();
          dt.TEST_VAL = data[0].TEST_VALUE;
          dt.Data = data.GroupBy(d => d.ID)
                         .Select(g => g.ToList())
                         .ToList();
          MyData.Add(dt);
     }
 }
```

The issue is dt.TEST_VAL will be different for differenr IDs and would like to get data in the format that was mentioned above and the yearwise data per ID will always be 3 items(2019, 2020, 2021). Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply changed MyCls like that

```
class MyCls
{
    public List<TestData> MyData {get;set;}
    public MyCls (List<MY_SP_Result> data)
    {
        MyData = new List<TestData>();

        foreach(var id in data.GroupBy(d => d.Id).Select(g => g.Key).ToList()) 
        {
            var dt = new TestData {
                TEST_VAL = id,
                Data = data.Where(d => d.Id == id).ToList()
            };

            MyData.Add(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (if I understand correctly what you are after):

```
public class MyCls
{
    public List<TestData> MyData { get; set; }
    public MyCls(List<MY_SP_Result> data)
    {
        var testValues = data.Select(d => d.TEST_VALUE).Distinct();
        MyData = testValues.Select(tv => new TestData
        {
            TEST_VAL = tv,
            Data = data.Where(d => d.TEST_VALUE == tv).ToList()
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Speed Tests of different solutions:

5x 10,000,000:

```
rvnlord:        10738   ms
daremachine:    13520   ms

rvnlord:        10428   ms
daremachine:    13704   ms

rvnlord:        10921   ms
daremachine:    13983   ms

rvnlord:        10978   ms
daremachine:    13608   ms

rvnlord:        10620   ms
daremachine:    13630   ms
```

Complete Test Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var testData = new MyCls(MY_SP_Result.GetData()).MyData;

            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Data\n");
            foreach (var td in testData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"--> [{i++}]");
                Console.WriteLine($"--> {td.TEST_VAL}");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tID\tYEAR\tVALUE\tTEST_VALUE");
                Console.WriteLine("\t------------------------------------------");
                foreach (var tv in td.Data)
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t[{j++}]\t{tv.ID}\t{tv.YEAR}\t{tv.VALUE}\t{tv.TEST_VALUE}");
                Console.WriteLine();
                j = 0;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class TestData
    {
        public int TEST_VAL { get; set; }
        public List<MY_SP_Result> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyCls
    {
        public List<TestData> MyData { get; set; }
        public MyCls(List<MY_SP_Result> data)
        {
            var testValues = data.Select(d => d.TEST_VALUE).Distinct();
            MyData = testValues.Select(tv => new TestData
            {
                TEST_VAL = tv,
                Data = data.Where(d => d.TEST_VALUE == tv).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class MY_SP_Result
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int YEAR { get; set; }
        public int VALUE { get; set; }
        public int TEST_VALUE { get; set; }

        public static List<MY_SP_Result> GetData()
        {
            return new List<MY_SP_Result>
            {
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 1, YEAR = 2019, VALUE = 78, TEST_VALUE = 3 },
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 1, YEAR = 2020, VALUE = 12, TEST_VALUE = 3 },
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 1, YEAR = 2021, VALUE = 56, TEST_VALUE = 3 },
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 2, YEAR = 2019, VALUE = 23, TEST_VALUE = 2 },
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 2, YEAR = 2020, VALUE = 89, TEST_VALUE = 2 },
                new MY_SP_Result { ID = 2, YEAR = 2021, VALUE = 34, TEST_VALUE = 2 },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Data

--> [0]
--> 3
                ID      YEAR    VALUE   TEST_VALUE
        ------------------------------------------
        [0]     1       2019    78      3
        [1]     1       2020    12      3
        [2]     1       2021    56      3

--> [1]
--> 2
                ID      YEAR    VALUE   TEST_VALUE
        ------------------------------------------
        [0]     2       2019    23      2
        [1]     2       2020    89      2
        [2]     2       2021    34      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This namespace contains an object to store data pulled from your procedure and an object to display the data:

```
namespace CustomObjectFromData
{
    // Represents an entry from your list of data
    class TestData
    {
        /* Replace 'public' with 'private' if you only want the value to be set at initialization. 
         * 'TEST_VALUE' has been replaced with 'seriesValue'. */
        public int id, year, value, seriesValue;

        public TestData(int id, int year, int value, int seriesValue)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.year = year;
            this.value = value;
            this.seriesValue = seriesValue;
        }
    }

    // Formats the data as you requested using 'ShowData'
    class DisplayList
    {
        // Edit these to edit the amount of spaces in a margin
        const string firstTab = " ";    // Space between edge and first index
        const string secondTab = "  ";  // Space between edge and TEST_VALUE
        const string thirdTab = "   ";  // Space between edge and data

        private List<TestData> values;

        // Initialize the list for the instance
        public DisplayList()
        {
            values = new List<TestData>();
        }

        // Adds 'toAdd' to the list of TestData entries.
        public void AddValue(TestData toAdd)
        {
            values.Add(toAdd);
        }

        public void AddFromList(List<TestData> list)
        {
            foreach (TestData element in list)
            {
                values.Add(element);
            }
        }

        // Format and show data as requested.
        public void ShowData()
        {
            // Default message if 'values' is empty.
            if (values.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data\n --> [Empty]");
                return;
            }

            // Find the amount of unique 'seriesValue' in 'values'
            List<int> uniqueSeriesValues = new List<int>();
            foreach (TestData element in values)
            {
                if (!uniqueSeriesValues.Contains(element.seriesValue))
                {
                    uniqueSeriesValues.Add(element.seriesValue);
                }
            }

            // Set up another list so that the values are grouped based on ID in ascending order.
            List<int> uniqueIdValues = new List<int>();
            foreach (TestData element in values)
            {
                if(!uniqueIdValues.Contains(element.id))
                {
                    uniqueIdValues.Add(element.id);
                }
            }
            uniqueIdValues.Sort();

            // Final variable setup before display
            int uniqueSeriesValuesCount = uniqueSeriesValues.Count;

            // Display data
            Console.WriteLine("Data");
            for (int i = 0; i < uniqueSeriesValuesCount; i++)
            {
                int currentIdValue = uniqueIdValues[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"{firstTab}--> [{i}]");
                Console.WriteLine($"{secondTab}--> Series Value: {uniqueSeriesValues[i]}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{secondTab}--> Data from ID '{currentIdValue}':");
                foreach (TestData element in values)
                {
                    int innerCounter = 0;
                    if (element.id == currentIdValue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{thirdTab}[{innerCounter}] {element.id, -5} {element.year, -7} {element.value, -7} {element.seriesValue}");
                        innerCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A script that implements this namespace:

```
    class Execute
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TestData> fromProcedure = new List<TestData>();
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(1, 2019, 78, 3));
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(1, 2020, 12, 3));
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(1, 2021, 56, 3));
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(2, 2019, 23, 2));
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(2, 2020, 89, 2));
            fromProcedure.Add(new TestData(2, 2021, 34, 2));

            DisplayList display = new DisplayList();
            display.AddFromList(fromProcedure);
            display.ShowData();
        }
    }
```

Further Instructions:

1. Obtain data from the procedure, and place it into a list of 'TestData' objects. The objects have the following format: **id**, **year**, **value**, **test_value**. In the implementation, I replaced the name 'TEST_VALUE' with series value.
2. Create an instance of the 'DisplayList' class
3. Use 'AddFromList' to create the data from the list.
4. Call 'ShowData' to print the data to the screen.

Hopefully this is compatible with the already existing code you wrote.